# Iphone app ios unknown key exception

Tags: ios

I keep getting this exception in xcode

```
2012-11-27 23:42:51.239 MichaelWidickProject[9640:c07] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2012-11-27 23:42:52.825 MichaelWidickProject[9640:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<InheritController 0x8e40cc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key you.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c93012 0x10d0e7e 0x1d1bfb1 0xb7d711 0xafeec8 0xafe9b7 0xb29428 0x2350cc 0x10e4663 0x1c8e45a 0x233bcf 0xf8e37 0xf9418 0xf9648 0xf9882 0xf9b2a 0x110ef5 0x110fdb 0x111286 0x111381 0x111eab 0x111fc9 0x112055 0x2173ab 0x6892d 0x10e46b0 0x228ffc0 0x228433c 0x2284150 0x22020bc 0x2203227 0x22038e2 0x1c5bafe 0x1c5ba3d 0x1c397c2 0x1c38f44 0x1c38e1b 0x1bed7e3 0x1bed668 0x1865c 0x1f6d 0x1e95)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I am trying to click a button and then make the button push a view controller onto a navigation view controller. I have tried everything I can think of. 
It is so weird that my professor couldn't figure it out. Please help

```
InheritController *gameOne = [[InheritController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BasicMathLevelOne" bundle:nil];
gameOne.title = @"Level One:Basic Game";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gameOne animated:NO];
```

Comment: did you have the line `[window makeKeyAndVisible];` in your App delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function? Assume you add your View Controller to the `window` (`UIWindow`)

Answer (score 1):

The error message sounds like a broken connection in "BasicMathLevelOne.xib". It is the result from KVC trying to set a value on your `InheritController` for the key "you" but the class has no KVC compliant accessor (any more?).

To find the exact spot where the error occurs set an exception breakpoint in Xcode (press Command-6, click the "+" in lower left corner, chose "Add Exception Breakpoint"). Running the app in the debugger should make it stop at the place where the error occurs.

Oh well, and get another professor.